# How to get a Recordset in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I've seen in Oracle SQL that there is something called `SYS_REFCURSOR` which is used in a SP to get a `recordset` from a table

I want to do the same thing in SQL Server so I can a SP to get a recordset of a specific table. I've searched a lot looking for similar solutions but all what I've seen are all related to Oracle SQL.

Any suggestions please?

P.S. To be more clear, what do I want is just using an SP to select all records instead of the normal query.

i.e. instead of using:

```
SELECT * FROM EMP_DEPARTMENT
```

use SP to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean stored procedure with SP you can to this :

```
create procedure dbo.spMyProcedure as
begin
    set nocount on
    select * from emp_department
end;
```

than you can do this :

```
exec dbo.spMyProcedure
```

Is this what you mean ?

Comment: Exactly, I thought about this code and already done it, but I thought it is not the efficient way to do it, please another question, how can I retrieve the result of this procedure in an ASP.NET C# code?

Comment: If all you do in the stored procedure is select * from emp_department than it is no more efficient than calling the select direct. In that case you would be better of in creating a view in stead of a procedure.

Comment: Retrieving the result in c# is the same as you would with a normal select statement. Put the 'exec spMyProcedure' in a SqlCommand and just do adapter.Fill() as you would do with a normal select

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can simply encapsulated the `SELECT` query in a stored procedure (using `*` only as an example since an explicit column list is the best practice):

```
CREATE PROC dbo.GetEmployeeDepartments
AS
SELECT * FROM EMP_DEPARTMENT;
GO
```

The SQL Server client API will stream the result as a fast-forwared read-only resultset, where individual rows can be used.